# Imagick convierte mal el texto de un pdf

Tags: php, imagemagick

Sere directo, tengo un problema despues de instalar imagick para convertir pdf a jpg cuando convierto un pdf con texto pues no lo convierte bien, aqui una muestra de lo que pasa:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el metodo que uso para convertir el pdf a imagen es el siguiente:

```
$objImgick = new Imagick();
                    $file = $data;
                    $path_name = pathinfo($file);
                    $directory = $path_name['filename'];
                    $bookpath = "paquete/$cliente/book/$directory/";
                    $objImgick->pingImage($file);
                    $numberpg = $objImgick->getNumberImages();
                    $html = "";
                    if (!file_exists($bookpath)){
                        mkdir($bookpath, 0755, true);
                    }
                    $valida ="SELECT index_path FROM bas_indice WHERE index_path = '$bookpath' AND uid = '$uid' AND book_name = '$libro' limit 1;";
                    $existe = pg_query($con,$valida);
                    $numrows = pg_num_rows($existe);
                    if($numrows==0){
                        for ($i=0; $i < $numberpg; $i++) {
                            if (!file_exists($bookpath."/$directory-$cliente-$i.jpg")){
                                $objImgick->setResolution(100,100);
                                $objImgick->readImage("{$file}[$i]");
                                $objImgick->setImageFormat('jpg');
                                $objImgick->setImageCompressionQuality(0);
                                $objImgick->borderImage('white',20,20);
                                $objImgick->writeImage($bookpath."/".$directory."-".$cliente."-".$i.'.jpg');
                                $objImgick->clear();
                                $objImgick->destroy();
                                $checkpoint = true;
                            }
                        }
```

El problema es que cuando es un pdf con imagenes todo funciona perfectamente, si alguien tuviera alguna idea, cabe mencionar que lo he desinstalado y reinstalado un monton de veces y no funciona.

P.D.
Mi sistema operativo es ubuntu 18.04